# DHCP disable client DDNS updates

Tags: dns, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have a DHCP server (ISC dhcp server version 3) set up on Ubuntu Maverick. The windows client in the network are trying to update their DNS name to the current IP address in the DNS zone by themselves (forward mapping). All linux clients are working fine, because the DHCP server does the DNS update for these clients.

How can i completely disable the DNS update of the Windows clients?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on Windows version.

### Windows XP

GUI:

1. *Control Panel* → *Network Connections*
2. right-click on the LAN connection → *Properties*
3. *Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)* → *Properties* → *Advanced*
4. Open the *DNS* tab, uncheck ***Register this connection's addresses in DNS***
5. *OK* * 3

CLI:

```
netsh inter ip set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp none
```

### Windows 7

GUI:

*No idea. Should be similar.*

CLI:

```
netsh inter ipv4 set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp none
netsh inter ipv6 set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp none
```

Comment: You're correct with regards to Windows 7. It's almost identical.

Comment: I'm sure that your suggestion works, but i want to configure my dhcp server to deliver all the settings to the client. In your suggestion i must manually configure each windows machine.

Comment: DHCP doesn't deliver that option, so I think you are stuck visiting each one or perhaps scripting it (unless you have a Windows domain, where you could use group policies).